# What does Zizek mean in this video?

Tags: zizek

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg7qdowoemo

1. Romantic love, especially in its infatuation stage, is evil.
2. Asserting that the world as it is, or a world imagined to be ideal, is the best state of affairs, is evil.
3. Both

If it were #1, I would strongly disagree with Zizek and am willing to disregard his works completely from now on, because it makes no sense. Romantic love and infatuation is what keeps the human race going, unless he is willing to say the human race itself is evil, which sounds like a half good scifi story plot but is not a realistic viewpoint (abusing the word "philosophy" here) upon which to live life.

Comment: Perhaps related to this statement of his I read (from The Puppet and the Dwarf, p. 115): 'Only a lacking, vulnerable being is capable of love: the ultimate mystery of love, therefore, is that incompleteness is in a way higher than completion. On the other hand, only an imperfect, lacking being loves: we love because we do not know all. On the other hand, even if we were to know everything, love would, inexplicably, still be higher than completed knowledge.' Maybe he's saying it's "evil" from the perspective that says love should be as "universal" as possible, but that he doesn't agree?

Comment: On the other hand, in *The Plague of Fantasies* Zizek does endorse Kant's idea that ethics should be based on universal maxims, see the discussion in Appendix III starting on p. 280 of the 2008 Verso Books edition). So perhaps he differentiates duty and love, and says the former should be as universal as possible while the latter should be particularistic.

Answer (score 1):

He says in the video “There is nothing more dangerous, more lethal for the loved person than to be loved, as it were, for not what he or she is, but for fitting the ideal.”

Zizek is a controversialist, he wouldn't be as well known as he is otherwise. If you can't sift through what are meant to be attention grabbing headlines, for the arguments of substance, then probably avoid his work. I find Zizek not very deep, but almost invariably entertaining in his writing. You can always rely on him to find some new provocation, and he does so from a place of intellectual integrity.

The absolute mincemeat he made of Jordan Peterson in debate with him, earns him a place as a talking-head public intellectual alone I'd say, also.

Comment: That quote isn't from the same video, various sources online say it was a comment of his in the movie "The Pervert's Guide to Ideology". So it may be expressing a somewhat distinct thought about love from the comment in the video.

Answer (score 0):

Quite coincidentally I answered a question about how to identify pseudo-experts or crackpots. Zizek is one of the crackpots. He misuses quantum physics. He says the universe is a kind of positively charged void. Whatever he means by *that*. It's reasonable to assume he doesn't even know himself. The balance of this void is disturbed, when particular things appear. What things does he talk about? Does he even know? I'm not so sure. Talking about quantum physics sounds impressive, but talking without understanding is quite crackpotty. He continues by saying that because of the imbalance things are really out there, which means that something went terribly wrong. Creation is a cosmic catastrophe. Things exist by mistake. To counteract this mistake there is love, which is a cosmic imbalance too.
The only sensible thing he says here that one imbalance (the cosmic imbalance of creation) is evened out by another (love). Regarding the rest, he does not know what he is talking about, or at least he doesn't show it from the words he uses. He merely uses quantum physics to empower and objectify his notion of love.
He continues that he always was disgusted by the idea that people love the world and by the idea of universal love. He doesn't like the world. Well, he hates it or he is indifferent towards it. He says he's somewhere in between, saying immediately after saying that that reality is out there, it's stupid, and he doesn't care about it so he's indifferent. Contradicting himself right after what he said before. He continues to say that love is a violent act, a structure of imbalance. What the F...? A structure of imbalance? Tell that to the one you are in love with. In the "infatuation stage". If you "pick someone", as he describes it, and say "I love you" to this person it's evil. It's the consequence of the structural imbalance. To pick someone is evil. The very act of picking is cruel and inspired only to counteract the cosmic imbalance... I don't see how this structural imbalance makes the intentions of a person (or even the person herself) uttering these words evil. He offers an incomprehensive, self-contradictory, incoherent, inconsistent, and certainly cynic approach to love. If you want to agree, it's up to you, I suppose. I think he wasn't upon picked much. This can be a source of deep contempt for the world.

Comment: He may have come across the idea of the universe initially being in a highly symmetric vacuum state, then going to a less symmetric state (ours) via "spontaneous symmetry breaking" (see [here](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast123/lectures/lec18.html) for discussion). "Positively charged" is obviously wrong if he's talking about something like electric charge, but it could have been a vague allusion to the idea that the highly symmetric vacuum state has a high potential energy but is unstable so it has a tendency to drop to a lower-energy asymmetric state, like a ball balanced on top of a hill.

Comment: As for "structure of imbalance", I believe he is talking about the *partiality* of love, that it's not based on some universal concern for all beings but on picking out one part of the universe to care especially about. That quote about the "structure of imbalance" comes right after his disparaging of "universal love", and the surrounding context is *'Love means, I pick out something, and you know, again it’s this structure of imbalance, even if this something is just a small detail, a fragile individual person, I say “I love you more than anything else.”'*

Comment: @Hypnosifl I'm not sure what he means by the structure of imbalance. I'm not even sure he knows himself! It sounds impressive and cold though. He effectively objectifies love by saying it's the counterbalancing force of by him so hated reality of the imbalanced and catastrophic creation of reality out of the void. I'm not sure why he says it's a positively charged void. I think he likes the nothingness of the pre-reality void (positively charged, that is nothing is positive) and he hates worldly things. He must have had bad experiences. He hates love, basically.